# Self referencing loop in Json.Net JsonSerializer from custom JsonConverter (Web API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

The project is an Asp.Net Web API web service.

I have a type hierarchy that I need to be able to serialize to and from Json, so I have taken the code from this SO: [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base), and applied the converter to my hierarchy's base class; something like this (there's pseudo-code here to hide irrelevancies):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TheConverter))]
public class BaseType
{
    // note the base of this type here is from the linked SO above
    private class TheConverter : JsonCreationConverter<BaseType>
    {
        protected override BaseType Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
        {
            Type actualType = GetTypeFromjObject(jObject); /*method elided*/
            return (BaseType)Activator.CreateInstance(actualType);
        }
    }
}

public class RootType
{
    public BaseType BaseTypeMember { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedType : BaseType
{

}
```

So if I deserialize a `RootType` instance whose `BaseTypeMember` was equal to an instance of `DerivedType`, then it will be deserialized back into an instance of that type.

For the record, these JSON objects contain a `'$type'` field which contains virtual type names (not full .Net type names) so I can simultaneously support types in the JSON whilst controlling exactly which types can be serialized and deserialized.

Now this works really well for deserializing values from the request; but I have an issue with serialization.  If you look at the linked SO, and indeed the Json.Net discussion that is linked from the top answer, you'll see that the base code I'm using is entirely geared around deserialization; with examples of its use showing manual creation of the serializer.  The `JsonConverter` implementation brought to the table by this `JsonCreationConverter<T>` simply throws a `NotImplementedException`.

Now, because of the way that Web API uses a single formatter for a request, I need to implement 'standard' serialization in the `WriteObject` method.

I must stress at this point that before embarking on this part of my project I had ***everything*** serializing properly ***without errors***.

So I did this:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, 
  object value, 
  JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}
```

But I get a `JsonSerializationException`: `Self referencing loop detected with type 'DerivedType'`,  when one of the objects is serialized.  Again - if I remove the converter attribute (disabling my custom creation) then it works fine...

I have a feeling that this means that my serialization code is actually triggering the converter again on the same object, which in turn calls the serializer again - ad nauseam. ***Confirmed - see my answer***

So what code *should* I be writing in `WriteObject` that'll do the same 'standard' serialization that works?

Comment: Nice Q&A, but it's worth pointing out that the serializer is doing the right thing: it inspects the object looking for custom serializers and finds one. You should be worried if it did anything else otherwise it might not respect custom converters on foreign classes.

Comment: @RupertRawnsley yep I agree with that

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well this was fun...

When I looked more closely at the stack trace for the exception, I noticed that the method `JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable` was in there twice, indeed it was that method one off the top of the stack - invoking `JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference` - which in turn was throwing the exception.  It was also, however, the source of the call to my own converter's `Write` method.

So it would seem that the serializer was doing:

- 1) If object has a converter

  - 1a) Throw if circular reference
  - 1b) Invoke converter's Write method
- 2) Else

  - 2a) Use internal serializers

So, in this case, the Json.Net is calling my converter which in turn is calling the Json.Net serializer which then blows up because it sees it's already serializing the object that was passed to it!

Opening ILSpy on the DLL (yes I know it's open source - but I want the 'callers' functionality!) and moving up the call stack from `SerializeConvertable` to `JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue`, the code that detects whether a converter should be used can be found right near the start:

```
if (((jsonConverter = ((member != null) ? member.Converter : null)) != null 
   || (jsonConverter = ((containerProperty != null) ? containerProperty.ItemConverter 
                                                    : null)) != null 
   || (jsonConverter = ((containerContract != null) ? containerContract.ItemConverter 
                                                    : null)) != null 
   || (jsonConverter = valueContract.Converter) != null 
   || (jsonConverter = 
       this.Serializer.GetMatchingConverter(valueContract.UnderlyingType)) != null 
   || (jsonConverter = valueContract.InternalConverter) != null) 
   && jsonConverter.CanWrite)
{
    this.SerializeConvertable(writer, jsonConverter, value, valueContract, 
                              containerContract, containerProperty);
    return;
}
```

Thankfully that very last condition in the `if` statement provides the solution to my issue: all I had to do was to add the following to either the base converter copied from the code in the linked SO in the question, or in the derived one:

```
public override bool CanWrite
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And now it all works fine.

The upshot of this, however, is that if you intend to have some custom JSON serialization on an object and you are injecting it with a converter ***and*** you intend to fallback to the standard serialization mechanism under some or all situations; then you can't because you will fool the framework into thinking you're trying to store a circular reference.

I did try manipulating the `ReferenceLoopHandling` member, but if I told it to `Ignore` them then nothing was serialized and if I told it to save them, unsurprisingly, I got a stack overflow.

It's possible that this is a bug in Json.Net - alright it's so much of an edge-case that it's in danger of falling off the edge of the universe - but if you do find yourself in this situation then you're kind of stuck!

Comment: I have to say this is not an edge case and there are a lot of threads related to this issue with custom JsonConverters. I appreciate the post. Thanks!

Comment: This completely sucks.  You have to manually try to embed the "$type" yourself, which the framework hides everything you need in private variables and classes, so you can't even use the serializer withing the WriteJson method of a JsonConverter.  Terrible.

Comment: I wrote my own framework and it does things right.  It allows you to read from or write to a dynamic object, and it handles embedding the type name and other special parameters outside the call.

Comment: + 1. Thank god someone finally wrote what this was about legibly..I've been going back and forth between exceptions and serialization to nothing!

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. I've been having a problem with a self-referencing loop and combing StackOverflow for answers for the past week, and this is finally the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this problem using version 4.5.7.15008 of Newtonsoft.Json. I tried all of the solutions offered here along with some others. I resolved the issue using the code below. Basically you can just use another JsonSerializer to perform the serialization. The JsonSerializer that is created doesn't have any registered converters so the re-entrance / exception will be avoided. If other settings or ContractResolver are used then they will need to manually set them on the serialized that is created: some constructor arguments could be added to the CustomConverter class to accommodate this.

```
    public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Use a privately create serializer so we don't re-enter into CanConvert and cause a Newtonsoft exception
        /// </summary>
        private readonly JsonSerializer noRegisteredConvertersSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            bool meetsCondition = false; /* add condition here */
            if (!meetsCondition)
                writer.WriteNull();
            else
                noRegisteredConvertersSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            // example: register accepted conversion types here
            return typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a simple solution to the re-entrance problem that also allows fallback - like it :)

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this myself and I was pulling my hair out in frustration!

To solve the issue, the following worked for me, but because I missed the `CanWrite` solution, it's a more complex workaround.

- Create a copy of the existing class on which you're using your Converter and call it something different.
- Remove the `JsonConverter` attribute on the copy.
- Create a constructor on the new class which takes a parameter of the same type as the original class. Use the constructor to copy over any values which are required for later serialisation.
- In your Converter's `WriteJson` method, convert the value into your dummy type, then serialise that type instead.

For instance, this is similar to my original class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyResponseConverter))]
public class MyResponse
{
    public ResponseBlog blog { get; set; }
    public Post[] posts { get; set; }
}
```

The copy looks like this:

```
public class FakeMyResponse
{
    public ResponseBlog blog { get; set; }
    public Post[] posts { get; set; }

    public FakeMyResponse(MyResponse response)
    {
        blog = response.blog;
        posts = response.posts;
    }
}
```

The WriteJson is:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
    JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (CanConvert(value.GetType()))
    {
        FakeMyResponse response = new FakeMyResponse((MyResponse)value);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, response);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

The OP pointed out that using an [Expando](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052%28VS.100%29.aspx) could be another possible solution. This works well, saving the bother of creating the new class, although DLR support requires Framework 4.0 or later. The approach is to create a new `dynamic` `ExpandoObject` and then initialise its properties in the `WriteJson` method directly to create the copy, e.g.:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
    JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (CanConvert(value.GetType()))
    {
        var response = (MyResponse)value;
        dynamic fake = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        fake.blog = response.blog;
        fake.posts = response.posts;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, fake);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a novel solution to the serious issue of when you really need to use both the converter and the standard serialization - since our JSON serializable objects *tend* to be light, having a copy isn't too bad in those situations.  I guess,  also,  an Expando might work too.

Comment: The Expando solution is very elegant. I can see quite a few other places where it would be useful in my project. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh yeah, except you completely lose the type information.  That won't write a "$type" field to the object, so forget deserializing it as a typed object, especially if the target member is an interface and needs a solid type embedded.  Also the framework hides everything you'd need to write the "$type" (let alone the object $id value) in private variables, making it next to impossible to embed such values yourself.  The JSON.NET framework has serious design flaws; virtually unusable.

Comment: @Triynko - You can write a `SerializationBinder` to add a custom `$type` property: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/11/19/json-net-4-0-release-4-bug-fixes It wasn't required for this example.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same plroblem with Parent/Child collections and found that post which has solved my case. I Only wanted to show the List of parent collection items and didn't need any of the child data, therefore i use the following and it worked fine:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ResultGroups, Formatting.None,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        { 
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

it also referes to the Json.NET codplex page at:

http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/272371

Comment: appreciate this, but this doesn't work in the case laid out in this particular question.

Comment: Sorry Andras, i thought the JsonSerializerSettings would help.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this is a serious limitation of the library.  The solution is quite simple, although I will admit it didn't come to me that quickly.  The solution is to set:

```
.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
```

which, as documented all over the place, will eliminate the self referencing error and replace it with a stack overflow.  In my case, I required write functionality, so setting CanWrite to false was not an option.  In the end I just set a flag to guard the CanConvert call when I know that a call to the serializer is going cause (endless) recursion:

```
    Public Class ReferencingObjectConverter : Inherits JsonConverter

        Private _objects As New HashSet(Of String)
        Private _ignoreNext As Boolean = False

        Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
            If Not _ignoreNext Then
                Return GetType(IElement).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) AndAlso Not GetType(IdProperty).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
            Else
                _ignoreNext = False
                Return False
            End If
        End Function

        Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)

            Try
                If _objects.Contains(CType(value, IElement).Id.Value) Then 'insert a reference to existing serialized object
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, New Reference With {.Reference = CType(value, IElement).Id.Value})
                Else 'add to my list of processed objects
                    _objects.Add(CType(value, IElement).Id.Value)
                    'the serialize will trigger a call to CanConvert (which is how we got here it the first place)
                    'and will bring us right back here with the same 'value' parameter (and SO eventually), so flag
                    'the CanConvert function to skip the next call.
                    _ignoreNext = True
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, value)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Function

        Private Class Reference
            Public Property Reference As String
        End Class

    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone, but in my case I was trying to override the Equals method to have my object be treated as value type.  In my research, I found that JSON.NET doesn't like this:

[JSON.NET Self Referencing Error](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22799)

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a simple mistake, and had nothing to do with the solution of this topic.

This topic was the 1st page in google, so I am posting here in case others would have same issue as I did.

```
dynamic table = new ExpandoObject();
..
..
table.rows = table; <<<<<<<< I assigned same dynamic object to itself.
```